# Query with CASE and generate_series(), order resulting timestamptz descending

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

I'm new and trying to create a function with the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_bulan()
returns table (request_detail timestamp with time zone)
language plpgsql stable
as $function$
        begin
        return query

        select
        case
        when (extract(DAY FROM now()) >= 25) then generate_series(date_trunc('year', now()), date_trunc('day', now()) ,interval '1 month')
        when (select extract(month FROM now()) = 2) then now() - (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,1))
        when (select extract(month FROM now()) = 1) then now() - (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,2))
        else generate_series((select date(date_trunc('year', now()))), (select date(now())-'1 month'::interval), interval '1 month')
        end
        order by timetstamptz(request_detail) desc;
        end;
        $function$;
```

The result from the query above is:

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00
2017-02-01 00:00:00
2017-03-01 00:00:00
2017-04-01 00:00:00
2017-05-01 00:00:00
2017-06-01 00:00:00
2017-07-01 00:00:00
```

I tried using `order by desc` and `order by timestamp desc` but it doesn't work. I want to make the order by descending so I get the result from 2017-07-01 to 2017-01-01. How do I do that?

Comment: Well bro, you want procedure or clear query?

Comment: what about procedure?

Comment: What is wrong with the result you get? Looks like properly sorted to me.

Comment: request_detail will be missing in case result , hence need to add a name to that @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: yes i do thank you sir :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to do that:

1. Add `as result_timestamp order by result_timestamp desc;`

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_bulan()
    returns table (request_detail timestamp with time zone)
    language plpgsql stable
    as $function$
       begin
       return query

       select 
       case
       when (extract(DAY FROM now()) >= 25) then generate_series(date_trunc('year', now()), date_trunc('day', now()) ,interval '1 month')
       when (select extract(month FROM now()) = 2) then now() - (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,1))
       when (select extract(month FROM now()) = 1) then now() - (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,2))
       else generate_series((select date(date_trunc('year', now()))), (select date(now())-'1 month'::interval), interval '1 month')
       end as result_timestamp order by result_timestamp desc;

       end;
       $function$;
   ```
2. Alternatively you can delete ordering from procedure and order when u call it from other place:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_bulan()
   returns table (request_detail timestamp with time zone)
   language plpgsql stable
   as $function$
           begin
           return query

           select 
           case
           when (extract(DAY FROM now()) >= 25) then generate_series(date_trunc('year', now()), date_trunc('day', now()) ,interval '1 month')
           when (select extract(month FROM now()) = 2) then now() - (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,1))
           when (select extract(month FROM now()) = 1) then now() - (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,2))
           else generate_series((select date(date_trunc('year', now()))), (select date(now())-'1 month'::interval), interval '1 month')
           end;

           end;
           $function$;
   ```

And calling:

```
select request_detail from public.get_bulan() order by request_detail desc
```

NOTE: the second one is much pliable and you can easily manipulate.

Comment: This is missing the core problem: contradicting sort order in the `CASE` branches. And more problems. I added an answer.

Comment: dude, it is alternative

Comment: OK, seems written in good faith and on topic. I removed the downvote. It's just not fixing the problem(s).

Answer (score 1):

```
 select
        (case 
        when (extract(DAY FROM now()) >= 25) then generate_series(date_trunc('year', now()), date_trunc('day', now()) ,interval '1 month')
        when (select extract(month FROM now()) = 2) then now() - (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,1))
        when (select extract(month FROM now()) = 1) then now() - (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,2))
        else generate_series((select date(date_trunc('year', now()))), (select date(now())-'1 month'::interval), interval '1 month')
        end) as time_st  order by time_st desc
```

Output:

```
2017-07-01 00:00:00+05:30
2017-06-01 00:00:00+05:30
2017-05-01 00:00:00+05:30
2017-04-01 00:00:00+05:30
2017-03-01 00:00:00+05:30
2017-02-01 00:00:00+05:30
2017-01-01 00:00:00+05:30
```

Answer (score 1):

The first and last branch of your SQL `CASE` statement return rows in descending order, the other two in ascending order. Hence you would need another `ORDER BY` in the outer `SELECT`.

The clean fix is to make all 4 branches return rows in the same order.

Or rather, completely rewrite this to untangle the mess:

```
SELECT *
FROM   generate_series(
         CASE
            WHEN extract(DAY   FROM now()) >= 25 THEN date_trunc('month', now())
            WHEN extract(MONTH FROM now()) <=  2 THEN now()
            ELSE                                      now() - interval '1 month'
         END
       , date_trunc('year' , now())
       , interval '- 1 month'  -- negative interval
      ) t(request_detail)
ORDER  BY request_detail DESC;  -- redundant
```

The negative interval produces descending order automatically. You can add `ORDER BY request_detail DESC` to make it clear and correct standard SQL.

Wrap the query into a function if you like.

Most importantly, ***don't*** wrap set-returning functions like `generate_series()` in a `CASE` statement. This was never a good idea, but starting with Postgres 10 it's going to raise an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
> ```

Demo:

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=24f3f79c22f1c6cba98b3826703e9c39)*